# Qt project file: !win32 uses

Tags: qt

My Qt creator is 32 bit. I know how to use win32 in my Qt project file but  i am not sure whether I can use !(not) with win32 or not.

I want something like below, but not sure whether it's correct way to use.

```
!win32 {
CONFIG += qtquickcompiler
}
```

PS:
It compiles without issues.

Comment: Usually, `win32` has nothing to do with 32-vs.-64-bit distinction. There's many systems/frameworks that use this term no matter the architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the conditions used in a given scope can be negated to provide an alternative set of declarations that will be processed only if the original condition is false. For example, suppose we want to process something on all platforms except for Windows. We can achieve this by negating the scope like this:

```
!win32 {
    SOURCES -= paintwidget_win.cpp
}
```